# How To Make An Html Text Input Vertically Scrollable & Starting Input From At The Top?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this text input:

```
<p><input type="text" style="height:500px;width:700px;"></p>
```

[click here to see the current input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNn2Z.png)

I would like it to look like this:

[click here to see the input i would like to have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZh0V.png)

I would like the input to be vertically scrollable and for the text to begin at the top rather than the middle.

Comment: use `<textarea></textarea>` instead of `<input>`

Answer (score 0):

```html
<p><textarea rows="4" cols="50">test</textarea></p>
```

you have to use `textarea` instead of `input`